# In what context is the hash of a ed25519 public key used as an address?

Tags: pda, account, address

According to the [docs](https://solana.com/docs/terminology#account), a Solana address is one of the following:

- an ed25519 public key
- a program-derived account address (32byte value forced off the ed25519 curve)
- a hash of an ed25519 public key with a 32 character string

The first 2 of these I've encountered numerous times, but I can't recall ever (knowingly) running into the third variation. Where is this used and what use case does supporting this type of address serve that user accounts and PDAs don't? I suppose they can be both on- and off-curve, but I don't really see any reason why you'd want that.

Comment: I think it might only be relevant when generating signatures , but it’s good question.  Not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That last one is more of a legacy use-case. Before there was the concept of program-derived addresses, many of the native programs allowed you to use addresses that were strings hashed with the signing pubkey.

You'll see most of these instructions contain `*_with_seed` somewhere, like `create_account_with_seed` https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/b3ea62fba31767fae75238a714081ab924cc6fbc/sdk/program/src/system_instruction.rs#L461

And these keys are created using `Pubkey::create_with_seed` https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/blob/b3ea62fba31767fae75238a714081ab924cc6fbc/sdk/program/src/pubkey.rs#L211

It would probably be better to deprecate these and use PDAs instead, but it's not too pressing an issue.

Comment: That clears things up, thank you Jon!